Match laminate tile
My house has laminate floor everywhere except in the bedroooms, which have carpet. I am beginning to remove the carpet in the bedrooms as a way to improve air quality, and I'd like to replace it with the same laminate that tiles the rest of the house. The previous owner left a couple of additional tiles of the same style, but not enough to tile an entire bedroom.
My question is, what resources can I use to try to identify the existing tile? It appears to be from 2020 from a date on the back of one tile. I've attached a few pictures.
The back of the tile reads as follows:
U 09/02/2020 - 5258
I've tried stores like Home Depot and Floor & Decor with no luck.


"My house has laminate floor everywhere except in the bedrooms, which have carpet." Apparently there's one room in your house that has a tile floor. Ha ha.... :)

If the flooring-only stores don't recognize it, it may nor be made anymore. Just have to keep shopping, and you may have to give up on an exact match and find something close enough.

+1 on you're probably gonna have to aim for "close enough."  You're going to need transitions anyway where the existing laminate (LVP?) ends at the bedroom thresholds.  That gray looks like you could find a dozen manufacturers in a similar shade.

"Apparently there's one room in your house that has a tile floor. " that picture was taken from the garage, which I guess technically does count as a room.

What you have is LVP, or Vinyl plank flooring, not tile.  Try taking a picture of just the floor plank and ask google to find it.

Looks like Great Lakes brand sold by Menards. I have that in my house and the back side is similar to mine. 

Looks promising. So far I haven't been able to find the same color, though the patterns do look similar.
